# How do I project a texture onto an object on a single axis instead of it wrapping around the object?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, node-editor, coordinates

I'm trying to get a texture to work along one axis but distort along another, I know this sound weird but I'm trying to emulate a corrugated card effect.

At the moment I have your standard node setup:

[image]

Please ignore the scaling, I'm doing using this effect along different sized parts and rather than scaling the UVs it seems easier to scale the texture.

I can't sadly share a blend file as the work is pretty NDA heavy but I can provide a photo of the file and a reference for what I'm looking to replicate.

You can see how in the real image of corrugated card, it is cut, thus giving the impression that the effect is stretched around the edge

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just as a side note, you can plug the same *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* node into each image because they're all using the same mapping.

Comment: Good idea, I never thought of that to be honest. Thanks Ray :)

I'm still not sure how to achieve this almost texture distortion apart from actually warping the UV by hand manually which would be very intensive as there are 23 parts all with different sizes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I've actually figured it out. If you put the camera in front view and project from view then it works perfectly :)

Hopefully this helps someone else as I know this can be really tough to achieve